# Android : Array of EditText

Tags: java, android

idI am developeing an app in android, In the layout i am using more than 20 **EditText**. To, reduce the size of my coding i was trying to implement **EditText** in an array .So, help me with how to implement the **Edittext** in an array and also how i should name the **EditText** in XML file to use it as an array.

I tried to implement this code but this is not working,

edittext reference in java file
    EditText[] et1 = new EditText[20];

and putting this into a for loop,

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
et1[i]=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext[i]);
}
```

but eclipse cannot properly resolve edittext[i].

tell me How do I properly create an array of EditText in my xml so that it is recognized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create edittext programaticaly as shown below:-

```
private EditText[] mEditTextPlayers;

public void goButtonClicked(View view) {
    maalContainer.removeAllViews();
    int numPlayers = Integer.parseInt((String) numberOfPlayers.getSelectedItem());

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext());
    mEditTextPlayers = new EditText[numPlayers];

    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
        //Pass the parent as the second parameter to retain layout attributes
        mEditTextPlayers[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_entry_item, maalContainer, false);
        maalContainer.addView(dynamicEntryView);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if it works for you or not :):-

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
ArrayList<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();

for(int i = 0; i < rootLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if(rootLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText) {
        editTextList.add( (EditText) rootLayout.getChildAt(i));
    }
}
```

Where `rootLayout` is the `View` containing all `EditTexts` (a `LinearLayout`, for example)

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a couple examples. First and foremost, this line is incorrect:

```
et1[i]=(EditText)findViewById(R.Layout.edittext[i]);
```

This is not how the `findViewById()` method takes a parameter. You can't append `R.id` to an array.

Now, you could do something like this: `id[] = new id[] {R.Layout.editTextOne, R.Layout.editTextTwo}`

When we sit back and think about this, we may realize it's going to take as much code (or more) as doing the following:

```
    EditText[] editTextArray = new EditText[] {
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oneEditText),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.twoEditText),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.threeEditText),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fourEditText),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fiveEditText),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sixEditText),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sevenEditText),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eightEditText),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nineEditText),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zeroEditText) };

    for (int x = 0; x < editTextArray.length; x++) {
        editTextArray[x].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // DO stuff here........................
            }
        });
    }
```

Lastly, DO NOT alter the xml file. Leave it be.

Answer (score 0):

First of all encapsulate your all of your 20 EditText inside a layout and provide that layout with an id something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edittext1"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edittext2"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edittext3"/>
    ...
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edittext20"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now inside your activity do something like this:

```
//Global variable
int index = 0;
EditText[] editTextArray = new EditText[20];

//inside activity
LinearLayout holder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.holder)
...
for(int i=0; i<holder.getChildCount(); i++){
    View view = holder.getChildAt(i);
    if(view  instanceof EditText){
        editTextArray[index++] = view;
    }
}
```

I have used LinearLayout for this example but you can use any layout.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works. Suppose you have a layout (id = "R1") with 9 EditText widgets. The following code will set up an array allowing you to access those widgets in an array:

```
    EditText[] etArray = new EditText[9];
    int index = 0;
    //store the EditText fields in an array
    LinearLayout LL = findViewById(R.id.R1);
    for(int i = 0; i < LL.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = LL.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof EditText) {
            //the following is the crucial line missing from the other answers
            etArray[index++] = ((EditText) v)
        }
    }
```

Now, you can access the elements of the array as in the following example:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        etArray[i].setText(Integer.toString(i));
    }
```